# How to convert 0.5 to 50 in php

Tags: php, number-formatting

Iam working with Lighthouse json file and the score they provide are all on decimals. my question is how to i convert them in php

```
 0.25 to 25
 0.5  to 50
 1    to 100
```

Comment: `input * 100`!?

Answer (score 4):

You could just multiply the value by 100.

`0.25 * 100 = 25` etc.